# Customize HostNameVerifier for multiple hosts and self-signed certificate

Tags: android, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an issue and need help of community.Now with changes in [Google data protection](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7188426) I received an warning in Google Developer Console.

> Security warning
>   Your app uses an unsafe implementation of HostnameVerifier.
>   For more information, including the deadline for resolving the vulnerability, please see this article in Google Help.
>   Applies to APK version 3.

The reason why I don't use `HostnameVerifier` properly is that our company can not provide signed 
with CA certificate to our every customer who bought our product. (It's up to his purposes to do that, if he wants so).
Our product contains a secured web service (Restful API) to communicate with the app. 
So on every installation there is generated new self-signed certificate which I should accept through the app, and obviously the simplest solution was to disable `HostnameVerifier` by:

```
private final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

And to trust all hosts:

```
private static void trustAllHosts() {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Who had similar experience with encryption? How should I proceed further in my case? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever heard of [Let's Encrypt CA](https://letsencrypt.org/)? 
If not check it out.

Hence your statement "*our company can not provide signed with CA Certificate to our every customer*" is wrong. 
You just have to integrate the Let's Encrypt client in your product and all servers will have a valid certificate at no costs.

Anyway even without a valid CA there are easy measures to make an SSL connection secure even with a self-signed certificate. The result will be not as good as as a real SSL certificate but much better that your "we disable the security of SSL/TLS" approach:

"Trust on first use" (similar the way SSH works). On first connection (assumable in a trusted environment) save a SHA-256 hash (or the certificate itself) presented by the server and save it. The next time an connection is established and the TrustManager's `checkServerTrusted`is executed you compare the leaf certificate with the saved one.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your detailed answer, I investigate it. Hope this will help to anybody, who has the same issue.